# Loop through array and remove stylesheets

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm building a site in `WordPress` and the plugins come with a few unwanted `css` files.

I'm trying to remove these stylesheets via JS but encountering a `Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '0' is not a valid selector.` error.

I'm trying to make it reusable so that I can add stylesheets to the array and remove easily, maybe even scripts too.

Unsure where I'm going wrong in my JS?

```js
const assets = ["link[href*='/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer.min.css']",
  "link[href*='/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css']"
]

for (var i in assets) {
  var cssElement = document.querySelector(i);
  cssElement.disabled = true;
  cssElement.remove();
  console.log(cssElement);
}
```

Comment: On the server-side, you should be able to prevent the sheet links from being sent to the client by hooking the ['print_styles_array'](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/print_styles_array/) filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `i` in your `for .. in` loop holds the index of the item at the current iteration, so on the first iteration, `i` will be equal to `0`. So to get the selector from you selector array, at each iteration, you'd need to pass `assets[i]` to the `quesrySelector` method.

Another thing, at every iteration, you should check if `querySelector` has found an element or not before trying to remove the expected element.

```js
const assets = [
  "link[href*='/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer.min.css']",
  "link[href*='/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css']"
];

let cssElement;

for (var i in assets) (cssElement = document.querySelector(assets[i])) && cssElement.remove();
/** the above line will only executed when "querySelector" has found an element on the page */
```

Another possible way to have the same effect is to use the `forEach` method:

```js
const assets = [
  "link[href*='/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer.min.css']",
  "link[href*='/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css']"
];

let cssElement;

assets.forEach(s => (cssElement = document.querySelector(s)) && cssElement.remove());
```

> Learn more about the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `for of` not `for in`. `i` in your case is the index but you want it to be the element in the array.

The error is saying that you passed `0` (which is the first index) to the `querySelector` which is not a valid DOM element

Answer (score 0):

```js
const assets = ["link[href*='/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer.min.css']",
  "link[href*='/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css']"
]

for (var i in assets) {
  var cssElement = document.querySelector(assets[i]);
  cssElement.disabled = true;
  cssElement.remove();
  console.log(cssElement);
}
```

```html
<link href="/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer.min.css" rel='stylesheet'/>
<link href="/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css" rel='stylesheet'/>
```